# Building R on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, r, arm, c99, raspberry-pi

I am building a software package using a custom built toolchain for the Raspberry Pi.

I've run into a C standard issue.  When compiling, I get an error that says SIZE_MAX is required for C99.

See here:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/njackson/R-2.15.3/src/unix'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/njackson/R-2.15.3/src/unix'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/njackson/R-2.15.3/src/unix'
making dynload.d from dynload.c
In file included from dynload.c:33:0:
../../src/include/Defn.h:209:3: error: #error SIZE_MAX is required for C99
make[3]: *** [dynload.d] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/njackson/R-2.15.3/src/unix'
make[2]: *** [R] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/njackson/R-2.15.3/src/unix'
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/njackson/R-2.15.3/src'
make: *** [R] Error 1
```

Comment: I *think* you can get Debian installed in which case you'd get r-base-core from Debian.

Comment: I need to use Arch Linux ARM.

Comment: Same thing, also .deb based -- try to use the prebuild .deb for the Arm architecture.

Comment: Arch Linux packages are .deb based??  The Arch Linux ARM repos don't have a pre-built packages from what I can tell.

Comment: Maybe I confused Arch.  Anyway -- use a .deb if you want prebuilt; built from source if that is your thing. Here is is how a friend deployed a *prebuilt* R on his thanks to Debian:  http://darrenjw2.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/r-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: I would suggest you to define it yourself to see if it is the only problem - I guess not. Direction of problems will give you more of an idea about what's wrong with your setup.

Comment: I went ahead and hacked the source code, it compiles, but when I reach the linking phase, it fails.  I'll look into it.

Comment: Hi Csreap3r did you have success installing R on Raspberry Pi?